# OpenTBS/TinyButStrong Is Not Replacing Merge Fields In DOCX

Tags: php, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I'm trying to use the OpenTBS/TinyButStrong library to replace merge fields in a word document.

We can take a very basic word document like this:

```
Hello, My Name Is Bob, My Age Is <<BOBAGE>>
```

Which in word has the following code:

```
{MERGEFIELD BOBAGE\*MERGEFORMAT}
```

And my code would be basic:

```
$TBS = new \clsTinyButStrong();
                            $TBS->PlugIn(TBS_INSTALL,OPENTBS_PLUGIN);
                            $TBS->LoadTemplate($path,OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);
                            $TBS->MergeField('BOBAGE','TEST');
                            $TBS->Show(OPENTBS_FILE,$tmpPath . 'test.docx');
```

When i open test.docx, the merge field isn't replaced!

It works if i use [bobage] which isn't actually a word merge field! That's not what i expected it to do, that's pretty useless.

Is there a way to replace the actual word merge fields?

Answer (score 0):

The instruction ̀`$TBS->MergeField()` is for merging TBS fields, not Ms Word Mail Merge Fields.

TBS fields are those like `[my_field]` or `[my_block.my_field]` in your template.

So your snippet could work if you have a piece of text in your template like `[BOBAGE]`.

By the way, OpenTBS can merges document fields if the type is IF field, but not MERGEFIELD. See the [documentation](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc#docfield) and examples for more details.